# How to swap images in a gridview

Tags: android, gridview, bitmap, imageview

I'm trying to swap images in a gridview and made this code:

```
        grd.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            counter ++;
            if(counter % 1 == 0){
                firstclick = position;
                data1 = crops.get(position);                    
            }                   
            else if(counter % 2 ==0){
                Bitmap swapImage = crops.get(position);
                crops.set(position, crops.get(firstclick));
                crops.set(firstclick, swapImage);
                grd.invalidateViews();
            }
        }
    });
```

I don't see why this code isn't working. when I start up my android the tiles don't swap when I'm clicking them. My imageadapter looks like this:

```
public ArrayList<ImageView> pics;
private ArrayList<Bitmap> crops;
private Context mContext;

public ImageAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<Bitmap> crops) {
    mContext = c;
    this.crops = crops;      
}

public int getCount() {
    return crops.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

// create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView;
    if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }

    imageView.setImageBitmap(crops.get(position));
    return imageView;
}
public void getpics(){
    for(int i = 0; i<getCount();i++){
        ImageView img = new ImageView(mContext);
        img.setImageBitmap(crops.get(i));
        img.setTag(i);
        pics.add(img);
        img = null;         
    }
}
```

}

First I want to try to swap images with each other, and then I want to try only swapping one specific tile in my bitmaparraylist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`counter%1` is always zero change you statements to these :

```
if (counter%2==1) {
 ....
} else {
 ...
}
```

and for swapping neighbor items , if counter starts from zero, do this :

```
if (counter % 2 == 1) {
      // swap item at counter with item at counter-1
      ...
}
```

and if counter starts from 1, do this :

```
if (counter % 2 == 0) {
      //swap item at counter with item at counter-1
      ...
}
```

Comment: any idea on only swapping neighbours?

Comment: ok, nice! The only problem are the neighbours above and the neighbours below. I tried to use:

grd.getNumColumns()

but this doesn't work on API 8 and requires minimal API level 11. Are there any other commands?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27299700/swapping-neighbors-in-a-gridview-error-in-the-edge

Answer (score 1):

just do like this .

In GridView,when you want to change a item , all you need is change the Adapter which you link to the GridView.

For example, swap two item:(GridAdapter extends ArrayAdapter)

```html
GridAdapter adapter = (GridAdapter)gridv.getAdapter();
String firstItem = adapter.getItem(firstPosition);
String secondItem = adapter.getItem(secondPosition);
adapter.remove(firstItem);
adapter.insert(firstItem, secondPosition);
adapter.remove(secondItem);
adapter.insert(secondItem, firstPosition);
```

You also can change other things in your custom Adapter by override the getView().